# Why its result is very poor using ssd_mobilenet_v1_pnp with my own dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Tensorflow 1.12.0

I am currently trying to train SSD_Mobilenet_V1_pnp model (pre-trained with COCO) with my dataset. My data set has 490 images for training, and 210 for evaluating, 23 classes

label_map.pbtxt:

item {
  id: 1
  name: 'a'
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: 'b'
}

...

pipeline.config:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 24
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_ppn"
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.99999989895e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.00999999977648
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.97000002861
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000475
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.99999989895e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.00999999977648
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.97000002861
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000475
            train: true
          }
        }
        depth: 512
        num_layers_before_predictor: 1
        kernel_size: 1
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.59999990463
        share_prediction_tower: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.15000000596
        max_scale: 0.949999988079
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.333299994469
        reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: false
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.300000011921
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.75
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.5
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 512
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.699999988079
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.13330000639
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "model.ckpt"
  num_steps: 50000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations\label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 210
  max_evals: 10
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations\label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "val.record"
  }
}
```

train:

```
python object_detection/model_main.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=pipeline.config --model_dir=train
```

log:

```
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.05s).
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50 | area= all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.75 | area= all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= all | maxDets= 1 ] = 0.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
```

Is this a normal?
How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Few things I notice that may help you out:

num_classes in your config file is at 24 but you are training 23 classes.

Also see you are using a fixed image resizer, depending on the dimensions of your photos this may be an issue since you are not maintaining aspect ratio.

Might see slight improvement by training for fewer steps (20k) since your data set is fairly small.

If none of this helps out would look into adding a hard data miner argument to config file to introduce a minimum number of negative examples.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/does-batch-size-in-keras-have-any-effects-in-results-quality

Comment: but still left: Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000  <Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000